# On the LCD for $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}$, given that $a, b, c, d$ are different integers between 1 and 25?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

> What is the least and greatest possible LCD for
>   $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}$, given that $a, b,
> c$, and $d$ are different integers between $1$ and $25$?

I believe the smallest possible least common denominator is 12, because if I pick $a=2$, $b=3$, $c=4$, and d=6, then the LCD for $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}$ will be $12$.

I don't know how to find the greatest possible LCD. Would it be $24\cdot 23\cdot 22\cdot 21$? Or maybe $23\cdot 19\cdot 13\cdot 11$ (only the primes between $1$ and $25$)?

Is there an easier way to find the least and greatest LCD for the different combinations of $a, b, c$, and $d$, without having to check for every possible combination? (there are $8855$ possible combinations).

Comment: By “$a,b,>c$ and $d$,” do you mean the following? $$a>c$$ $$a>d$$ $$b>c$$ $$b>d$$

Comment: If $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ have to be different you can always assume that "both $a$ and $b$ are greater than both $c$ and $d$", or whatever is intended by the strange $>$ sign in your text. I suggest you remove it.

Comment: The ">" sign is a typo. It's just "a, b, c , and d" with only requirements being that they are different integers between 1 and 25.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach to the least is very good.  Since your result is so small, it is not hard to try all the smaller cases and show that none of them work.  Even if between allows the ends, you can't beat $12$.  You could also use $1,2,3,4$ but that gets $12$ as well.  For the greatest, you don't want to repeat primes.  The greedy approach is a good one.  Take $24$, but that prohibits any numbers with factors of $2$ or $3$ because (for example) $22$ is no better than $11$.  Then $23, 19, 17$ and you are done.  You can see that $24 \cdot 23 \cdot 19 \cdot 17$ beats your candidates.  If you choose $24,23,22,21$ the LCD is $24 \cdot 23 \cdot 11 \cdot 7$ because of common divisors.  Again, there are not many candidates that are greater and you can show that each one fails.

Comment: Of course, I misread it, sorry.